# openshot and qbittorrent quits after after being launched

Tags: kubuntu, openshot, qbittorrent

running: Kubuntu 11.04x64

Both programs quit right after being launched and I get the following errors when running each applications from the terminal:

**OpenShot:**

```
--------------------------------
   OpenShot (version 1.3.0)
--------------------------------
Process no longer exists: 5485.  Creating new pid lock file.
state saved
The program 'openshot' received an X Window System error.
This probably reflects a bug in the program.
The error was 'BadMatch (invalid parameter attributes)'.
  (Details: serial 25 error_code 8 request_code 132 minor_code 19)
  (Note to programmers: normally, X errors are reported asynchronously;
   that is, you will receive the error a while after causing it.
   To debug your program, run it with the --sync command line
   option to change this behavior. You can then get a meaningful
   backtrace from your debugger if you break on the gdk_x_error() function.)
```

**QBitTorrent:**

```
qbittorrent: symbol lookup error: qbittorrent: undefined symbol: _ZN10libtorrent7sessionC1ERKNS_11fingerprintEii
```

***EDIT (7.13.11):***

I removed qbittorent from my computer:

```
sudo aptitude purge qbittorrent
```

I removed the GetDeb repository from my sources.list file (actually just commented them out), updated my database and reinstalled qbittorrent:

```
sudo aptitude install qbittorrent
```

Don't know why but this application seems to launch properly, with the exact same versions of QBitTorrent (v2.8.2-0) and LibTorrent-RasterBar6 (v0.15.6) as before.

**Still have the problem with OpenShot Video Editor, so could really use help with that if anyone has any ideas as to what the problem is.  Thank You.**

Comment: I would remove your answer and add it as an edit to your question. Also a solution to the getdeb repository is to disable the repo temporarily downgrade the relevant packages and lock them http://askubuntu.com/questions/18654/how-to-prevent-updating-of-a-specific-package then you can re-enable the getdeb repo and report the problem to openshot and qbittorrent I presume they already know but it doesn't hurt

Answer (score 2):

Update qbittorrent from PPA. or downgrade, if tou use ppa. it's all because of libtorrent-rasterbar6 update. downgrade this package, or upgrade qbittorrent from ppa

The kind of error you experience at qbittorrent usually happens when qbittorrent is built against one version of libtorrent and executed against another. Could you please check you system to make sure you don't have several versions installed ? like for example one in /usr/lib and one in /usr/local/lib?

Comment: I googled my problem w/ qbittorent before I posted my question here and saw others having similar problems that was solved by the method you mentioned but I had no such luck... but I did manage to get the application working by removing the repo for GetDeb... not an ideal solution as it is I'd like to keep GetDeb so if you or anyone else has another ideas I'd very much appreciate the help.  Thank You.